# Tool for editing sprites contour pixel alpha value

Tags: sprites, antialiasing

I have seen that most games uses sprites that have a transparent contour, that is, the pixels that belongs to the contour of the object in the WxW sprite image is below 255. It is not perfectly opaque, so that when you render it on screen, you avoid aliasing effects.

Is there a tool that automatically loads N .png sprites and process them in order to make their contours semi-transparent?

Comment: Anti-aliasing of a line is typically done when exporting the original format, because only then will the program know what angle the line was meant to be (crucial for determining the different opacities). Doing this later is non-trivial, as just semi-transparenting the line would not fully get rid of the aliasing effects (and may destroy a wanted strong outline). One way to get back to smoother outlines might be to depixelize first -- http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/kopf/pixelart/ -- then resize to lower resolution again, now keeping the original anti-alias information.